# If $\alpha$ is a root in $Z^5+Z^3+Z+3=0$, then find $\alpha$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $\alpha$ is a root of $Z^5+Z^3+Z+3=0$, then find $\alpha$.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

If $\alpha$ is a root of $Z^5+Z^3+Z+3=0$, then

**A)** $|\alpha| \geq 1$

**B)** $|\alpha|<1$

**C)** $\alpha$ lies on or outside the circle $|z|=\frac{1}2$

**D)** $\alpha$ lies inside the unit circle $|z|=1$

**My Attempt**: I tried using Rouche’s theorem, but I am unable to get my desired answer.

Comment: Is there a difference between B and D?

Comment: Clearly by seeing u can say it’s -1

Comment: @NamburuKarthik That's not the only one, though.

Comment: The existence of $-1$ is sufficient to solve this problem as you can immediately cross out $B,D$ and also notice $A$ implies $C$  but not the other way around.

Comment: @cr001 No but if there is another root such that $ |\alpha|<1 $, then you cannot rule out the other options, so we need to prove that this holds for all roots.

Comment: First $B,D$ cannot be true for all roots because they are not true for $-1$. Next if $A$ is true then $C$ must be true, no matter what the number is. And there is only one correct answer.

Comment: **Hint:** Try to prove by contradiction. Assume $|\alpha|<1$ and use $|x+y+z|\le |x|+|y|+|z|$.

Comment: @cr001 Does the question assumes that it should hold for all roots? I mean, it's just saying that if $\alpha$ is a root, then what are the possibilities....

Comment: I think the option which holds for all

Comment: Yes it should hold for all roots and the logic to cross out $B,D,A$ applies for all roots.

Comment: How to find complex roots for biquadratic

Comment: $Z^4$- $z^3$ +2$z^2$ -2z +3

Comment: Through calculator the values I found , all are out of lZl=1

Comment: @NamburuKarthik all values do not satisfy $|z|=1$. Check [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E4-x%5E3%2B2x%5E2-2x%2B3%3D0)

Comment: I told out of lZl=1 not on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $|\alpha|\lt 1$. We have, $$\Big(|\alpha^5+\alpha^3+\alpha|=3\Big)\le|\alpha|^5+|\alpha|^3+|\alpha|<3$$ which is a contraction. Hence, $|\alpha|\ge1$.

Comment: Thank you @SarGe

Comment: You're welcome! :-)